# Spring Boot application with Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

i would have need some tips/help here. I have nearly 0 experience with jquery but i might need it.

in my controller i have this :

```
@RestController
public class mainController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
    String res = drive.checkFile("cwg");

    return res;
}
```

for now, i succeeded to display the res in my view with jquery get.
But i need to go further.

in my view (index.html), i need to pass the parameter with (jquery method?) a form and display the res.

like :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
    String res = drive.checkFile("***HERE PARAMETER***");

    return res;
}
```

I probably needed a POST ans GET method. but i have no idea how to achieve that.
How to pars parameters to a controller method via html.

thx very much

Comment: Please, check [this tutorial](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/)

Comment: thats nice to put -1 and not answered at all thx very mutch  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to modify your method as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@RequestParam String inputParameter) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
    String res = drive.checkFile(inputParameter);
    return res;
}
```

The section modified is
Instead of `Model model` we used `@RequestParam String inputParameter` as an argument.

and from JQuery call this GET method and pass param as QueryString

---

Update:
Your JQuery Method should similar to this:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "/index",
    type: "get", //send it through get method
    data: { 
      inputParameter: value , // your get parameter(s)
      inputParameter2: value2, 
      inputParameter3: value3
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //Do Something on successful Ajax call
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      //Do Something to handle error
  }
  });


});
```

refer to the below links:

- [AJAX request for REST service in Jquery, Getting response when parameters are sent through URL but not through data object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187821/ajax-request-for-rest-service-in-jquery-getting-response-when-parameters-are-se)
- [How to send parameters with jquery $.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544160/how-to-send-parameters-with-jquery-get)

Comment: Hello, i almost got it, but here i have done :  i have : the get  $.get("/index",{"query": que}, function .... and i catch up the parameter "que" with input val(). but here the issues, the get is trigged only once. how to trigged  $.get again ? i tryed this but with no succes :  $( "input" )
        .keyup(function() {
            var value = $( this ).val();
            $( "p" ).text( value );
        })
        .keyup();